# problem to get response from Yelp API

Tags: iphone, yelp

Yelp API V2.0 have problem to get response .when i send request in yelp API V2.0 with all authentication key and token , i get error missing parameter . if any one have idea regarding Yelp help me

Comment: If you look at the response, it should include the missing field.

Comment: http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=food&location=San+Francisco&oauth_consumer_key=mykey&auth_consumer_secret=mykey&oauth_token=mykey&oauth_signature=mykey&oauth_signature_method=blank&oauth_timestamp=blank&oauth_nonce=blank  and i got this error massage {"error":{"text":"One or more parameters are invalid in request","id":"INVALID_PARAMETER","field":"oauth_timestamp"}}

Answer (score 1):

If you get this error:

```
{"error":{"text":"One or more parameters are invalid in
request","id":"INVALID_PARAMETER","field":"oauth_timestamp"}}
```

then your timestamp is sometime in the past.  You can resolve this by dynamically getting the current time or by setting the timestamp parameter to some arbitrary value in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You got that error because you are not using the keys themselves "The OAuth credentials are invalid" `...oauth_consumer_key=mykey&auth_consumer_secret=mykey...`
it should look like this `...oauth_consumer_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&auth_consumer_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX...`

Have a look at their github https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/ they have some examples that might help for example on the PHP

```
// Set your keys here
$consumer_key = "";
$consumer_secret = "";
$token = "";
$token_secret = "";
```

you should set your keys in between the quotes `$consumer_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";`